# serialize javascript array of object with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, serialization

Good day! Could anyone suggest please, is it possible to serialize/unserialize array of object in JavaScript and do not lose nested arrays? I want to save it into the database but when I unserialize json I lose prices array.

I use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse.

```js
const arr = [{
  "HotSpotData": "<SchematicsDefinition><Schema2D><Rectangles><RectangleDefinition ZOrder=\"0\" Top=\"440\" Left=\"176\" Width=\"27\" Height=\"27\" ShapeType=\"2\"/></Rectangles></Schema2D></SchematicsDefinition>",
  "Ptr": 24580100323769,
  "Ptr": 24588687801988,
  "Ptr": 24773374403522,
  "Qty": 1,
  "Desc": "",
  "Ptr": 24588687801988,
  "Reference": 1,
  "id": 25,
  "notes": "",
  "Code": "1831001",
  "Description": "REEL CARRIER ",
  "Ptr": 24558623176188,
  "Notice": "",
  "Order": 1,
  "PartImage": null,
  "prices": [{
    "pricePtr": 24648817311745,
    "priceValue": 1970.9,
    "priceCaption": "USD LIST",
    "currency": "USD"
  }],
  "rnd_unic": 1597222193169
}]


console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr)))
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I do not see the issue

Comment: Thanks. I will check.